# How do I get the latest tag value from the github API for a given repository

Tags: json, git, github

I can get the latest commit from the GitHub api using :

```
$ curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/dwkns/test/commits?per_page=1'
```

However the resulting JSON doesn't contain any reference to the tag I created when I did that commit.

I can get a list of tags using :

```
$ curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/dwkns/test/tags'
```

However the resulting JSON, while it contains the names of tags I want, is not in the order in which they were created - there is no way of telling which tag is the latest one.

EDIT : The latest tag created was `LatestLatestLatest`

My question then is what API call(s) do I need to do to get the name of the latest tag in my repository?

Answer (score 2):

Using `jq` in combination with `curl` you can have a pretty straightforward command:

```
curl -s \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/dwkns/test/tags \
  | jq -r '.[0].name'
```

Output (as of today):

```
v56
```

Explanation on `jq` command:

- `-r` is for "raw", avoid json quotes on jq's output
- `.[0]` selects the first (latest) tag `object` in json `array` we got from github
- `.name` selects the `name` property in this lastest json `object`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Maybe useful for someone: dropping the `jq` pipe gives a very nice & informative API response to work with. The endpoint is also public, which is a cherry on top

Answer (score 2):

## Semantic Versioning Example

NOTE: If you're in a hurry and don't need all the fine details explained, just jump down to "***The Solution***" and execute the command.

This solution uses `curl` and `grep` to match the **LATEST** [semantically versioned](https://semver.org) release number. An example will be demonstrated using my own Github repo "[pi-ap](https://github.com/f1linux/pi-ap)" (a pile of bash scripts which automates config of a Raspberry Pi into a wireless AP).

You can test the example I give you on the CLI and after you're satisfied it works as intended, you can tweak it to your own use-case.

### Versioning Format Construction:

Since we're using `grep` to match the version number, I need to explain its' construction. 3 pairs of integers separated by 2 dots and prefaced by a "v":

```
vXX.XX.XX
 ^  ^  ^
 |  |  |
 |  |  Patch
 |  Minor
 Major
```

NOTE: If a field only has a single digit, I'll pad it with a zero to ensure the resulting format is predictable: always 3 pairs of integers separated by 2 dots.

### The Solution:

Github Username:  ***F1Linux***
Github Repo Name: ***pi-ap*** (NOTE: exclude the "***.git***" suffix)

```
curl -s 'https://github.com/f1linux/pi-ap/tags/'|grep -Eo "$Version v[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}"|sort -r|head -n1
```

### Validate the Result Correct:

In your browser, go to:

```
https://github.com/f1linux/pi-ap/tags
```

And validate that the latest tag was returned from the command.

The above is fairly extensible for most use-cases. Just need to change the user & repo names and remove/replace the "v" if you don't use this convention in tagging your repos.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
curl -s https://github.com/dwkns/test/tags |
awk '/tag-name/{print $3;exit}' FS='[<>]'
```

Or

```
#!/bin/awk -f    
BEGIN {
  FS = "[<>]"
  while ("curl -s https://github.com/dwkns/test/tags" | getline) {
    if(/tag-name/){print $3;exit}
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about scraping the website but was hoping to do it via the API. Seems like an oversight that you can't (at least not obviously). Also your bash version, while it gives the right tag, also produces a '(23) Failed writing body' error. Any ideas on why?

Comment: @dwkns requires GNU awk I think